# TransformXml task failed while packaging

Tags: msbuild, wix, wix3.7

Hi when I try to do packaging stuff in MSBuild and build the solution.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="%(ProjectReference.FullPath)" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=AnyCPU" Condition="'%(ProjectReference.WebProject)'=='True'" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <LinkerBindInputPaths Include="%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Was getting "TransformXml" task failed error.Not sure How to fix it.

```
  Error 3   The "TransformXml" task failed unexpectedly.
    System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
       at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
       at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
       at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets    1496    6   SCBUDirectMSI
```